# filter dataframe by maximum element from groupby pair

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of four columns

```
df=DataFrame({'order_id':[134,101,131,159,101,189,120,102,134,130,231,421,141,129,141,101],\
          'user_id':[24,10,24,12,24,10,10,24,21,12,12,10,12,17,24,12],
          'product_id':[1004,1041,1078,1001,1001,1074,1001,1019,1021,1004,1001,1010,1004,1004,1017,1004],
         'sector':['a','a','b','d','c','a','c','a','c','a','b','c','a','b','a','a']})

order_id    product_id  sector  user_id
    120      1001          c     10
    421      1010          c     10
    101      1041          a     10
    189      1074          a     10
    159      1001          d     12
    231      1001          b     12
    130      1004          a     12
    141      1004          a     12
    101      1004          a     12
    129      1004          b     17
    134      1021          c     21
    101      1001          c     24
    134      1004          a     24
    141      1017          a     24
    102      1019          a     24
    131      1078          b     24
```

For each product_id I want to filter the dataframe by selecting the rows of  each (product_id,user_id) 
pair that have a greater order_id value than the maximum order_id associated with the (product_id, user_id) pair

For example, for product_id 1001, the max order_id associated with user_id 10 is 120, the max order_id
ssocited with user_id 12 is 231, and for user_id 24 the max order_id is 101, so for product_id 1001, I would
like to return the DataFrame

```
df2=DataFrame({'order_id':[421,189,134,141,102,131],
'product_id':[1010, 1074,1004,1017,1019,1078],
'sector':['c','a','a','a','a','b'],
'user_id':[10,10,24,24,24,24]})

order_id    product_id  sector  user_id
    421        1010       c         10
    189        1074       a         10
    134        1004       a         24
    141        1017       a         24
    102        1019       a         24
    131        1078       b         24
```

For product_id 1004, there is no data associated with user_id 10, so no rows are returned. For user_id 12 the largest
order_id is 141 and is associated with 1004. Since no order_id's associated with user_id 12 are larger, no rows are returned.
For user_id 17, there is only one entry and it is associated with product_id 1004, so there are no other product_id's
associated with user_id 17. There can be no greater order_id's. Finally, for user_id 24, the largest order_id associated 
with product_id 1004 is 134. In this case product_id 1017 has an order_id of 141, so its row must be returned.

To summarize the output for product_id 1004 is

```
  order_id  product_id  sector  user_id
    141        1017       a        24
```

I want to repeat this for all product_id's, and store the dataframes in a list

I think the solution centers around grouping by user_id and then filtering on the order_id and product_id but I'm stuck with this

```
df3=df.groupby(['user_id'])
for key, val in df3:
    d=val.sort_values(['order_id','product_id'])
    print d
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What's not working?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  If (for `product_id` 1001), the max `order_id` is 231.  Why are there values for `order_id` in your expected output that are less than this threshold?

Comment: @Alexander the max order _id associated with product_id 1001 and user_id 12 is indeed 231. No rows are required to be returned because the max order_id of user_id 12 is 231. I only want order_id's that exceed the max order of the product_id for a given user_id. The problem is very confusing and i did my best to summarize it.

Comment: I still don't understand your logic.  You may want to consider extending your example.

Comment: additional example provided

Comment: `df.groupby(['product_id','user_id'])['order_id'].max()`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this is the most efficient solution out there, but it works:

```
def get_dataframe_for_product_id(your_input_df, wanted_product_id):
    df2 = your_input_df.groupby(['user_id'])
    result = pd.DataFrame([],columns=your_input_df.columns)
    for key, val in df2:
        result = pd.concat([result, val[val.order_id > val[val.product_id == wanted_product_id].order_id.max()]])
    return result
```